# method to attach JFrame with html page in java

Tags: java

Applets easily embed  with in a html page, but when I'm using an applet instread of a `JFrame` I am facing  many  problems. I want to  directly  embed a `JFrame` within a html  page. Is there is a  method to embed/run a Java file in a `JFrame` and another Swing component in a html page.

Answer (score 0):

The last time I created an applet, I added a JPanel to the JApplet in the init method.

```
@Override
public void init() {
    highScores = new MinesweeperHighScores();
    highScores.readScores();

    MinesweeperGameType gameType = MinesweeperGameTypeFactory
            .getGameType(highScores.getGameType());
    MinesweeperGameStatus gameStatus = new MinesweeperGameStatus(gameType);
    MinesweeperPanel panel = new MinesweeperPanel(gameType, gameStatus,
            highScores, this);

    add(panel.getMainPanel());
    setSize(gameType.getSize());
}
```

Comment: this  is  an  example    to  use  swing  component with   in Applet , my  problems also  can  be  solved in  this  way. But i  just want  to  know like applet, is  there  is  any  method to  attach JFrame with in  HTML.

Comment: @Gayatri Thakur:  I'm not aware of any method to attach a JFrame to an HTML page.